# Shared libraries in phone apps

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, qmake

I am trying to port this (https://github.com/jobe-m/ownkeepass) keepass app to Ubuntu Phone. I am just at the beginning an want to include the needed libraries and plugins. I didn't write a UI yet.

My current problem is that gcrypt.h is not found by the Keepass plugin.
I just don't know, how to link the libraries correctly for Ubuntu Phone.

I am using qmake and my code currently looks like this:

```
password_generator_qmldir.path   = /usr/share/$${TARGET}/lib/harbour/ownkeepass/PasswordGenerator
password_generator_qmldir.files += \
    ../common/qml/imports/PasswordGenerator/qmldir
password_generator_lib.path   = /uKeepass
password_generator_lib.files += \
    ../common/qml/imports/PasswordGenerator/$$ARCH_LIBS/libPasswordGenerator.so \
    ../common/qml/imports/PasswordGenerator/$$ARCH_LIBS/libgcrypt.so.11 \
    ../common/qml/imports/PasswordGenerator/$$ARCH_LIBS/libgpg-error.so.0

INSTALLS += \
    password_generator_lib \
    password_generator_qmldir \
```

I admit, that I don't really know, what the qmldir is for.

Thanks in advance,
Moritz

Comment: Isn't the default KeePass2 app available in Ubuntu Phone?

Comment: I didn't find anything like Keepass for the phone. I think Keepass2 doesn't run on Mir and we would have to wait for XMir. If you have any additional information, please share ;)

Comment: There is a [feature request](https://www.keepassx.org/dev/issues/302) raised exactly for this. Until that is implemented, you can use either the *command-line* version or *JavaScript* version [listed here](https://www.keepassx.org/dev/issues/302). They should work universally.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I think your second link is wrong, because it points to the feature request too.

Comment: Oops, sorry abt that! Here is the correct one: http://keepass.info/download.html